# How Can remove 'italic' element inside the 'pub-id', 'italic' element not allowed inside the 'pub-id'

Tags: xslt-2.0

We are trying to move the any tags under the `section` elements, if tags are preceding-sibling of `section` and following-sibling of `section` elements.

Please see the example below and suggest!
Thanks for advance!

**input:**

```
<section><para>text here</para></section>
    <!-- Move below para in the preceding section -->
    <para><g>other txt</g></para>
    <parablock><g>txt</g></parablock>
    <list>list here</list>
    <section><para>another section para</para></section>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<section>
    <para>text here</para>
    <para><g>other txt</g></para>
    <parablock><g>text</g></parablock>
    <list>list here</list>
</section>
<section>
    <para>another section para</para>
</section>
```

Comment: You've shown a template rule that matches IT elements but there are no IT elements in your input, so we can't see what it's doing; we also can't see what the $content parameter is set to. You haven't provided enough context. If you don't get an answer to an XSLT question on SO it's usually because it's not a well-thought-out question.

Comment: See this link XSLT fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94humrx

Comment: In the input has more hierarchy of <section> element, so unable to find the solution

Comment: My last comment was added automatically when I voted to close this question as a duplicate of your other question.

Comment: Okay @DanielHaley Can you look again on my question, because I unable to get the result

Comment: It is Humble request, Please look again on my question